# Product Tag issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tags

I think this issue is not new but still not found a solution:

We tagged products in a multilanguage shop (de and en)
See this example:

http://www.belladonna.de/en/tag/Ring

How can we assure, when clicking on a product, not to be forwarded to the default shop but rather remain on the selected shop language in order to avoid a 404 error ?